# Doctrine ODM / MongoDB not retrying queries?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine ODM to connect to MongoDB. I have a three node replica set: two fulls and one arbiter. Replication is solely for higher availability, I don't seek to distribute reads across nodes. My application is logging `MongoCursorException`s every so often with the message `not master and slaveok=false`. I don't see any evidence that a failover event occurred in the mongodb logs and the primary didn't change. CORRECTION: **failover had indeed occurred**, but the exception with `not master and slaveok=false` was appearing often, even showing up 6 hours after a new primary was successfully elected.

What to do? I see our version of [doctrine-mongodb](http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb) includes [(experimental?) retry functionality](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/pull/35), but I don't see an easy way to enable that.

Not sure if it matters, but this is a Symfony2 (v2.0) app.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/6p710Rdycpg/discussion implies that we *need* retries (emphasis mine):

> Your application must be written to reconnect/retry since there are 
>   any number of transient (network) errors which could come up much like 
>   the rolling upgrade process during **normal operation**.

The [Mongo PHP extension docs](http://php.net/class.mongocursorexception) seem to account for this:

> The driver will automatically retry "plain" queries (not commands) a couple of times if the first attempt failed for certain reasons. This is to cause fewer exceptions during replica set failover (although you will probably still have to deal with some) and gloss over transient network issues.

And I thought `doctrine-mongodb` just used the PHP extension to actually talk to mongod. So I'm left a bit confused whether or not I *should* have to worry about retry configuration.

I think I solved part of the problem: I **removed the arbiter** from the connection string following [this advice from Kristina Chodorow](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/3RCCEdQAAYk/ChCI5PEudEgJ). I'm no longer seeing any `MongoCursorException`s with the message `not master and slaveok=false`. I might have been hitting https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-392.

However, I'm still getting a few `MongoCursorException`s with the message `couldn't determine master` during failover. For example, I just did a failover; based on the mongod logs, a new primary was elected after a few seconds, but the web application was throwing that exception even 5 minutes later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using one of the tags (up to 2.2.1 at this time) corresponding to the 2.0 branch on DoctrineMongoDBBundle. Symfony 2.1+ compatibility is in tag versions 3+ of the bundle.

The configuration class exposes `retry_query` and `retry_connect` options, which default to zero, at the document manager level. In YML, the configuration would look like:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    # Other proxy, hydrator and connection configuration options

    default_document_manager: dm1

    document_managers:
        dm1:
            retry_query: 1
            retry_connect: 1
            # Other mapping, metadata and DM options follow
```

I realize this wasn't mentioned in the [bundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html), so I just added a section on it in [this commit](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/commit/bcfb6aa9cdcf616b1e844bf71090986d88519c2d).

Comment: Thank you, I've upgraded bundles to the versions you recommend in the docs. To test the new settings I need to set up a replica set in my dev environment and simulate failover--I'll do that tomorrow. Two questions. 1) do you recommend using 1 for both `retry_query` and `retry_connect`? 2) with the new bundles, I'm running into an issue where a string id in a BSON document (`_id: "141"`) is becoming an integer when I access the field on a mapped PHP object. Do I have to do something special so it remains a string in PHP, like it used to?

Comment: You would do better to ask Jon Wage about the retry options, as he's using them at OpenSky. The right answer probably varies by use case, as there is a trade-off with delaying the request with retry attempts vs. simply catching the error and moving on from there. Regarding your second question, I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/444) with a failing test case. Let me know if the test describes your situation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try asking Jon about the retry options. Yes, that pull request hits the nail on the head.

Comment: I never heard back from Jon, but I just did a manual failover while upgrading my replica set from 2.2.1 to 2.2.2. I saw errors (warnings?) in the MongoDB logs like `not master and slaveOk=false`, but these didn't seem to cause server errors, so I take that to mean connect & query retrying is working as expected. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the replicaSet option to point to your designated replica set configured within MongoDB?

[Symfony DoctrineMongoDBBundle Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html)

Look at the full configuration at the bottom. As far as I know you need to name all the servers in the server config line **AND** name the replicaSet in the options section. The documentation on that page doesn't make that very clear.

Looking through the code. It looks like the retry system should be configured by setting.

```
retryConnect
retryQuery
```

At the same level as the database name.

This is an example of my Zend Framework config which essentially does the same thing.

```
; Database details
resources.odm.configuration.defaultDB = "test"
resources.odm.connection.options.replicaSet = "test-replica-set"
resources.odm.connection.server = "mongodb://rs1a.testing.com:27017,rs1b.testing.com:27017,rs1c.testing.com:27017"
resources.odm.configuration.retryConnect = 3
resources.odm.configuration.retryQuery = 3
```

I was getting similar errors when I didn't have the replicaSet configured.

Comment: I've configured `doctrine_mongodb.connections.default.options.replicaSet = true` and `doctrine_mongodb.connections.default.server = mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019` (substituting `localhost` for real hosts/IPs/ports here) (Symfony2 config looks a little different than Zend).

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the lines I think are correct for the retry system. If it's still not right I'll delete the answer until I can try it out properly on my setup.

Comment: Thanks Jamie! I do see those retry settings in the doctrine-mongodb code, but Symfony2 wraps the Doctrine MongoDB configuration with `DoctrineMongoDBBundle`, so there may not be an easy way to set these in Symfony2.

Comment: Also, see the other update I just made. Seems like the Mongo PHP extension should already be doing retries.